# Defining 2014 SQL Backup and Restore Process

Tags: vmware-vsphere, sql-server-2014

I have an Vmware vsphere environment with 3 vlans, Prod,Test and Dev. The client has 6 SQL servers within the production environment and wants to make full,differential and transactional log backups.

My question is, I have defined the backup processes with schedules and everything but I don't know how to safely implement a restore process.

Do you need a separate environment to test the backups? The client is worried to restore anything within the same network that could cause conflicts within the production servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all servers are sitting on the same domain